# Как избегаеть data races используя semaphore?

Tags: c++, winapi

Начал работать из semaphore (WinAPI) и не могу понять как при его использовании избегать data races. Например:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

HANDLE semaphore;

const int THREADS_COUNT = 10;
const int SEMAPHORE_MAX_VALUE = 3;

int global = 0;

DWORD WINAPI func(LPVOID)
{
    DWORD waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(semaphore, 0);
    switch (waitResult)
    {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            global++;
        }
        ReleaseSemaphore(semaphore, 1, NULL);
        break;
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        std::cout << "ID = " << GetCurrentThreadId() << " wait\n";
        break;
    }
    Sleep(3000);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    semaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, SEMAPHORE_MAX_VALUE, SEMAPHORE_MAX_VALUE, NULL);

    HANDLE threads[THREADS_COUNT];

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, func, NULL, 0, NULL);
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(THREADS_COUNT, threads, true, INFINITE);

    for (auto& el : threads)
    {
        CloseHandle(el);
    }

    CloseHandle(semaphore);

    std::cout << "global = " << global;

    return 0;
}
```

в итоге значение global всегда разное. Как єтого избежать? Мне нужно использовать например еще CRITICAL_SECTION? Или я вообще неправильно использую semaphore? Буду благодарен за ответ и возможно даже пример кода по правильному использованию semaphor'a =)

Comment: Здесь вам конечно же надо использовать critical section. semaphore и медленнее, и вообще немного для другого (разделение доступа разного типа, например, читатели и писатели).

Answer (score 2):

В данном конкретном примере с веселым счетчиком, примитивы синхронизации не нужны совсем. Для этого есть `std::atomic<>`

- никто не будет дергать ядро
- код более читабельный
- вы не привязаны к конкретной ОС

Вообще, начиная с C++11, первым приоритетом выбора для синхронизации являются средства самого языка, а где-то третьим-четвертым (после boost, Qt, libpthread наконец) будут таки примитивы из API ОС.

Answer (score 1):

Основная проблема вашего кода в том, что семафор изначально создается со со значением счетчика до `SEMAPHORE_MAX_VALUE`, тем самым позволяя до `SEMAPHORE_MAX_VALUE` потоков *одновременно* дождаться `WaitForSingleObject` и начать работу. Тогда как в данном случае для предотвращения состояния гонки возможность работать и модифицировать `global` должен иметь максимум один поток. По сути в этой ситуации нужен семафор со счетчиком до 1, то бишь работающий как аналог `CRITICAL_SECTION`. То бишь семафор тут не нужен, вместо него следует использовать `CRITICAL_SECTION`, а еще лучше - SRW lock (не являются объектами ядра, соответственно устроены проще и работают шустрее, но только в рамках одного процесса).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но тогда в каком случае вообще использовать семафор? Можете показать пример кода, пожалуйста?